# systemd session below user session

Tags: linux, development-environment, systemd

Is it possible to run a systemd session below the user session with unit files in a subdirectory and not installed in `~/.config/systemd`?  I'm developing a system consisting of different services (implemented in C++), some of which depend on each other.  Currently, they're run from a bash script and all write to stdout.  I would love to be able to start them from the build directory, e.g.

```
# enter build directory
cd /path/to/project/build
# start services
systemd --root ./systemd-units &
# check status of services
systemctl --root ./systemd-units status
# check log output of services
journalctl --root ./systemd-units
```

Unfortunately no such option exists and I couldn't find any alternative.  I don't want to use docker because it makes debugging unnecessarily difficult.

Is there a way to do what I want with systemd?  I looked into other systems and [runit](http://smarden.org/runit/) seems to be able to do what I want but is unlikely to be used in the final product.

Answer (score 0):

It sounds like you may want to use the [`link`](https://www.freedesktop.org/software/systemd/man/systemctl.html#link%20PATH%E2%80%A6) feature of systemctl, so you can link units that are not the search path into the search path.

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. To critique or request clarification from an author, leave a comment below their post. - [From Review](/review/low-quality-posts/21034233)

Comment: @Liam,  I believe my suggestion will answer his question. I wasn't attempted to critique or clarify the author's question. Frank, did using the "link" feature of systemctl address your issue?